# Storage settings

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, storage, deploy

I would like to deploy my smart contract but I don't know what to put as parameters in the storage (I'm new to tezos). Thank you very much to those who will take the time to help me :)

```
//FA2
'(pair (pair (pair (address %admin) (big_map %ledger nat address))
            (pair (big_map %metadata string bytes) (nat %next_token_id)))
      (pair (pair (big_map %operators (pair address (pair address nat)) unit)
                  (big_map %reverse_ledger address (list nat)))
            (big_map %token_metadata nat (pair (nat %token_id) (map %token_info string bytes)))))' ;

//FA2
'(pair (pair (pair { Elt "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" } { Elt 1 "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" })
            (pair { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e } { 0 2 }))
      (pair (pair { Elt (pair "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" 1) unit }
                  { Elt "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" (list nat)) }
            { Elt 0 (pair 1 { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e)))) }' ;
```

my deploy.ts file:

```
import { TezosToolkit } from '@taquito/taquito'
import { importKey } from '@taquito/signer'
import * as fs from 'fs';

const provider = 'https://rpc.hangzhou.tzstats.com'

async function deploy() {
 const tezos = new TezosToolkit(provider)
 await importKey(
 tezos,
  'hpdcsnao.ixquxooo@teztnets.xyz', //mail
  'ZSrbDk3Nzf', //password
  [
    "sky",
    "inquiry",
    "build",
    "man",
    "aunt",
    "topic",
    "pattern",
    "image",
    "giant",
    "burger",
    "shock",
    "banner",
    "safe",
    "initial",
    "big"
].join(' '),
'My Secret' //private key
)

try {
const op = await tezos.contract.originate({
  //smart contract code
  code: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./nft2.json").toString()),
  //storage state
  init: '(Pair (Pair (Pair "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { Elt 1 "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" }) (Pair { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e } 2)) (Pair (Pair { 1 1 } { Elt "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" 1 }) { Elt 1 (Pair 1 { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e }) }))'
})
//beginning to deploy
console.log('Awaiting confirmation...')
const contract = await op.contract()
//deployment report: amount of used gas, storage state
console.log('Gas Used', op.consumedGas)
console.log('Storage', await contract.storage())
//operation hash one can use to find the contract in the explorer
console.log('Operation hash:', op.hash)
} catch (ex) {
console.error(ex)
 }
} 
deploy()
```

But the parameters that I provide in the deploy file, in my init variable are not good, I am trying to understand which parameters to pass.

Error :
[image]

Comment: Updated the answer below with a complete example. https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-kalam-dbjg9k?file=/index.js (in the link, the expected Micheline is printed to the browser console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [michelson-sdk](https://romarq.github.io/michelson-sdk/FA2) to generate the Michelson values (Micheline or Michelson JSON).

```
// Micheline:  (Pair (Pair (Pair "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { Elt 1 "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" }) (Pair { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e } 2)) (Pair (Pair {  } { Elt "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { 1 } }) { Elt 1 (Pair 1 { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e }) })) 

import {
  Record,
  Address,
  Nat,
  Big_map,
  String,
  Bytes,
  Map
} from "@tezwell/michelson-sdk/literal";

const storage = Record(
  {
    admin: Address("tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr"),
    ledger: Big_map([
      [Nat(1), Address("tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr")]
    ]),
    metadata: Big_map([
      [
        String(""),
        Bytes(
          "0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e"
        )
      ]
    ]),
    next_token_id: Nat(2),
    operators: Big_map([]),
    reverse_ledger: 
       Big_map([[Address("tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr"), List([Nat(1)])]
    ]),
    token_metadata: Big_map([
      [
        Nat(1),
        Record({
          token_id: Nat(1),
          token_info: Map([
            [
              String(""),
              Bytes(
                "0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e"
              )
            ]
          ])
        })
      ]
    ])
  },
  [
    [
      ["admin", "ledger"],
      ["metadata", "next_token_id"]
    ],
    [["operators", "reverse_ledger"], "token_metadata"]
  ]
);

console.log("Micheline: ", storage.toMicheline());
console.log("Michelson JSON: ", storage.toJSON());
```

I can help with further questions about using the package, let me know if the documentation is not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Can you share the "nft2.json" file? The screenshot above does not give enough information.

Comment: "reverse_ledger" value was wrong. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much ! it works ! :)